# Clojure: a tail recursion to get leaf counts of a trie

Tags: clojure

I have a trie data structure using hash-map. I want to count its leaves, but my tail-recursion is too slow: I think I'm using wrong data structures. Please help.

I believe the `(vec trie)` part is stupid, please correct me!

## trie definition

```
(defn add-to-trie [trie x]
  (assoc-in trie x (merge (get-in trie x) {:terminal true})))
```

so the trie would be like this:

```
(def trie 
  (reduce add-to-trie {} (map #(re-seq #"\S" (.trim %1)) ["x" "y" "abt" "act"])))

{"a" {"c" {"t" {:terminal true}}, 
      "b" {"t" {:terminal true}}},
 "y" {:terminal true},
 "x" {:terminal true}}
```

## recursive version

I work around a recursive one:

```
(defn terminal-count [root] 
  (if (:terminal root) 
    (+ 1 (terminal-count (dissoc root :terminal)))
    (apply + (map terminal-count (vals root)))))
```

## ugly tail-recursion

```
(defn terminal-count2 [trie] 
  (loop [cnt 0 nodes (vec trie)] 
    (cond 
      (empty? nodes) cnt 
      :else          (let [des (val (last nodes))]
                       (cond 
                         (map? des) (recur cnt (vec (concat (pop nodes) des)))
                         :else      (recur (inc cnt) (pop nodes)))))))
```

I found the second one is 30 times slower then first one, on a 130 thousand 8~16 character strings. I must use wrong data structure (converting trie to a vec is ugly I think) or did stupid things.

PS. using vector as queue is bad practice, is that a key point of my problem ?

Comment: Why is using a vector as a queue bad practice?

Comment: Why don't you just cache the leaf-count so you don't have to do a full walk every time?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: if you pop the queue with 'rest' or 'next', it returns a seq rather than a vector that you expected. then you'll need to use 'into' to get the seq back to vector, it's O(n) efficient. That's the bad things I did in my case.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus A vector *keeps its head*: a reference to any sub-vector retains the whole vector. The memory occupied by a vector-as-queue grows with every `conj` and is never recovered while the queue persists. You may have made the front of the vector-queue invisible (by retaining only a trailing sub-vector). Nevertheless, Clojure retains the whole vector.

Comment: A more revealing set of words is `["a" "b" "ac" "abt" "act"]` - where `"ac"` is a terminal internal node of the trie. Two of us, myself and @dAni, failed to deal with this case, pointed out to me by  @ValentinWaeselynck.

Comment: @Choulin If you're using a vector as a queue, you can pop it in quick constant time with `(fn [q] (subvec q 1))`. However, the storage cost is the whole vector, not just what remains in your queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct about vectors being the performance issue.

The main bottleneck is in the recursion `(vec (concat (pop nodes) des))`. Here you are creating a brand new vector and copying the content of `nodes` plus the dec on each recursive call, so you are not reusing the existing `nodes` vector. I get a x2 performance improvement changing that line to `(apply conj (pop nodes) des)` as this one is "updating" the existing `nodes` vector.

The same solution but using lists shows the same performance as Valentin's transients and perhaps is a little bit cleaner. This particular solution is just 50% slower than your recursive version:

```
(defn terminal-count3 [trie]
   (loop [cnt 0 nodes (seq trie)]
      (if (empty? nodes) 
          cnt
          (let [des (val (first nodes))]
            (if-not (:terminal des)
              (recur cnt (concat des (rest nodes)))
              (recur (inc cnt) (rest nodes)))))))
```

A more idiomatic solution (as Valentin suggests) is to return a lazy seq of all terminal nodes and to count it. This solution is more reusable, shorter and the fastest, just 20% slower than your recursive version:

```
(defn terminal-nodes [trie]
   (lazy-seq
     (if (:terminal trie)
       (if (= 1 (count trie))
         trie
         (cons trie (terminal-nodes (dissoc trie :terminal))))
   (mapcat terminal-nodes (vals trie)))))

 (def terminal-count4 (comp count terminal-nodes))
```

Comment: thank you for elaborating the bottleneck,and the 'terminal-count4', that's what I want. For this simple problem, all the transform of data structure is nothing about the problem itself, it's about the language, and I want language as less noticeable as possible.

Comment: the (:terminal trie) makes {:terminal true, {some other nested k-vs}} exit too early. For instance, a trie out of ["aat" "abt" "a" "b"] terminal-count4 return 2. I figuree out dissoc in my first completion, but don't know how to work around here. Thank you.

Comment: Your recursive version, `terminal-count4`, fails to deal with internal terminal nodes, as did mine - pointed out to me by @ValentinWaeselynck.

Comment: Fixed. I had to add the if (= 1 (count trie)) condition to make it reasonably faster.

Comment: `terminal-count3` is likewise faulty: on the trie of `["a" "b" "ac" "abt" "act"]`, it returns 2 instead of 5. Change `(if-not (:terminal des) ... )` to `(if (map? des) ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed one can assume that persistent data structures do not offer optimal performance for this kind of computing.

May I suggest instead the use of [transients](http://clojure.org/transients), which are in a nutshell mutable implementations of Clojure collections. This would result in something like the following:

```
(defn terminal-count-transient [trie] 
  (loop [cnt 0,nodes (transient (vec trie))] 
    (cond (t-empty? nodes) cnt 
          :else (let [des (val (t-last nodes))
                      remaining-nodes (pop! nodes)] 
                  (cond 
                    (map? des) (recur cnt, (reduce conj! remaining-nodes des)) 
                    :else (recur (inc cnt) remaining-nodes))))))
```

Where I have defined 2 helper functions `t-last` and `t-empty?` for transient vectors (not all of the read-interface for Clojure collections has been extended to transients yet) :

```
(defn t-empty? [t-vec]
  (= (count t-vec) 0))

(defn t-last [t-vec]
  (t-vec (dec (count t-vec))))
```

I cannot pretend this is optimal, but on my machine this performs twice better than the recursive version you defined above.

The other options I can think of are :

- Use lazyness. (From what I have tried, you can easily get something that is 'only' twice slower than the recursive version). You can for example define a function that returns a lazy seq of the leaves, then `count` it.
- Use regular mutable java queues, e.g `java.util.ArrayDeque`. Probably heavier to use, but quite fast.

Comment: thank you Valentin. I'll definately look into 'transient'. I used to think it's a sin to use mutable data structure, recently I realised it's ok if only use in a self-contained code block, right?

Comment: Yes, the 'sin' with mutable data structures is to share them.

Answer (score 2):

Edited to repair the errors pointed out by @ValentinWaeselynck.

---

A recursive version avoiding modifications to the data is

```
(defn terminal-count [root]
  (apply
    +
    (map
      (fn [[k v]] (case k, :terminal 1, (terminal-count v)))
      root)))
```

This ought to be *slightly* faster.

An easy way to avoid the recursive call is to use [`tree-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/tree-seq) to generate a lazy sequence of the nodes, and count the terminal ones:

```
(defn terminal-count [root]
  (count (filter :terminal (tree-seq map? vals root))))
```

Comment: thank you. glad to see a built-in macro to do this. But I found tree-seq's lazy-seq is approximately O(n^2) of original searching space. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Choulin I found `tree-seq` to be a little slower than linear. I used it count the nodes of trees with up to five million or so nodes. The trees were calculated on the fly. The fertile nodes had 9 children, and the depth was more or less uniform for any one tree. The code for timing the count of the 5 million strong tree is `(time (let [children (fn [n] (let [big (* 10 n)] (map #(+ big %) (range 1 10))))
      fertile? (partial > 1000000)]
  (count (tree-seq fertile? children 0))))`. It might be a stronger test to use a smaller fanout - two, say - and more depth.

Comment: @Choulin ... and I tried a couple of tricks to speed up [`tree-seq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4535). Neither worked. Removing the enclosing `lazy-seq` made it *twice as slow*! Unwinding `(mapcat f coll)` into `(concat (map f coll))`  - short-circuiting an `apply` - made no discernible difference. By the way, `tree-seq` is a function, not a macro.